# Struct argument inside a function definition that is in a different file

Tags: c++, file, struct, visual-studio-2013

I have an assignment that I have to use different files for my functions and I don't have to use a Header file. The problem is that the compiler is showing me various errors. All the errors are exactly the same for all my functions.

This is the **error :**

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Asignacion 1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>
> 1>  SortCompany.cpp
>
> 1>c:\users\emanuel\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\asignacion 1\asignacion 1\sortcompany.cpp(1): error C2065: 'Elemento' : undeclared identifier
>
> 1>c:\users\emanuel\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\asignacion 1\asignacion 1\sortcompany.cpp(1): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'Dealer'
>
> 1>c:\users\emanuel\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\asignacion 1\asignacion 1\sortcompany.cpp(1): error C2182: 'SortCompany' : illegal use of type 'void'
>
> 1>c:\users\emanuel\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\asignacion 1\asignacion 1\sortcompany.cpp(1): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
>
> 1>c:\users\emanuel\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\asignacion 1\asignacion 1\sortcompany.cpp(2): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
>
> 1>c:\users\emanuel\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\asignacion 1\asignacion 1\sortcompany.cpp(2): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

(Same errors as above for all files.....)

> 1>  Generating Code...
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

---

I have the main.cpp which is the main file (obviously). The main calls "Menu.cpp" and the Menu calls all the other functions in the other files.

PD: Elemento[] is a struct

Menu.cpp code:

```
using namespace std;

//these functions are fine
void Closing(ifstream &, ofstream &);
void Opening(ifstream &, ofstream &);

//the problem is here with all these functions
void Registro(Elemento[], int &, ifstream &);
void InfoDealer(Elemento[], int, ofstream &);
void SortCompany(Elemento[], int);
void MayorVentas(Elemento[], int, ofstream &);
void MayorVentasPorMarca(Elemento[], int, ofstream &);



#include "Registro.cpp"
#include "InfoDealer.cpp"
#include "SortCompany.cpp"
#include "MayorVentas.cpp"
#include "MayorVentasPorMarca.cpp"

void Menu()
{
//code here...
}
```

**Registro.cpp:**

```
void Registro(Elemento Dealer[], int &Cantidad, ifstream &entrada)
{
//code here...
}
```

**main.cpp:** (This file is default. I shouldn't change it.)

```
//include stuff
using namespace std;

const int MAXIMODEALERS = 20;
const int MAXIMOMODELOS = 6;
struct Detail
{
    string ModelName;
    int Sales;
};
typedef Detail Detalle;

struct Element
{
    string   CompanyName;
    Detalle  Modelo[MAXIMOMODELOS];
};
typedef Element Elemento;

Elemento Dealer[MAXIMODEALERS];

int Cantidad;

void Menu(void);


#include "Menu.cpp"

void Opening(ifstream &Entrada, ofstream &Salida)
{
//code
}

void Closing(ifstream &entrada, ofstream &salida)
{
//code
}

int main()
{
    Menu();
    return 0;
}
```

All the remaining files have the same structure as Registro.cpp

Hope you can help me! If you need more details, ask for it please.

Comment: Are you sure this is a *C++* course, and not a *C* course?

Comment: Any suggestions? crush...?

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of your classes?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I added the main.cpp but we still are not working with classes. The next assignment is to change this program to class :P

Comment: You're not supposed to include `.cpp` files. You should be including header files instead. Put the classs and the declaration of their methods into `.h` files, and use the `.cpp` files to implement those functions. Inside `main.cpp`, simply do `#include "Registro.h"`, `#include "Menu.h"...`.

Comment: I know that but for this assignment it has to be this way. :/

Comment: @emanuel1337 May I ask why? Did someone teach you to include .cpp files?

Comment: How are you compiling your program? Are you using the command line?

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody taught me how to include .cpp files. But the professor provided the main.cpp and menu.cpp. Those files have the include stuff, the struct declarations and function prototypes. I'm compiling with F7 (Build Solution) I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You should forward-declare classes and structs before their usage. Add `struct Elemento;` before functions. And anyway you cannot use `ifstream` without including `ifstream` at lease somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I included all the libraries in the main.cpp. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every name that is used in a translation unit must be declared first, above the statement that uses it. For example your function `Registro` is using the name `Elemento`. The compiler has no idea about it, so you must first declare it somewhere to specify its type. The same applies for `ifstream` and `ofstream`. Also, I think you are trying to link `Menu.cpp` and all the definitions of the functions in other files. Then you're in trouble, because there are multiple definitions of every function, one definition when you `include` it in `Menu.cpp` and the other in every source file. When you link all this you get two definitions for every function. Also, note that this is a bad design. You should never `include` `.cpp` files. That is `NOT` because you are not allowed to. The preprocessor doesn't care if you `include` `.cpp` or `.abcdef` files. They are all just text files. With this, I mean you should not include `definitions` in your translation unit because they can cause you serious headaches, and this is really bad desgin you can't count on.  Here is a good explanation how to organize your code. Hope this helps!

Something to add:

I saw your comment bellow. Yes, `Element` is `defined` (not declared) in main.cpp. But, because you are compiling all these files separately the compiler has no idea what exists outside the translation unit `unless` you specify it. So, it won't know the name `Element` if you not `declare` it before its usage. I think you have small understanding of some notions like: translation unit, preprocessing include-s, linkage, scope, storage duration etc. Take your time to read it so everything becomes much clearer.

[How to successfuly organize your source code in files.](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798)